# IXMLDocument exclude xml declaration

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-2006, xmldom

I am trying to get xml text from an IXMLDocument like so.

```
Doc.XML.Text;
```

This gives me the xml text but it includes the xml declaration.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Is there a way I can get the xml text excluding the xml declaration. I could always remove it manually myself from the string result, but I feel like there should be property or something which I can set on the document to exclude the xml declaration.

**Example**

Doc.XML.Text outputs

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Certificates>
  <Certificate>
  </Certificate>
</Certificates>
```

Comment: Read it from `Doc.DocumentElement.XML` instead.

Comment: @TLama that does work, but it excludes the first tag from the xml as well.

Comment: It shouldn't be, since `DocumentElement` points at the `<Certificates>` node, and asking a node for its XML is supposed to include that node in the output.

Comment: @TLama Doc.DocumentElement.XML is the answer

Comment: I tested it, `DocumentElement.XML` works fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can read it from the `DocumentElement.XML` property. The [`DocumentElement`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLDocument.DocumentElement) property provides access to the root node of the XML document and [`XML`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNode.XML) returns the XML content of a node.